# How to hide FragmentTabHost android layout when soft keyboard appears?

Tags: java, android, layout, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

How to fix the tab at the bottom it moves up when I am trying to use the search (`EditText`) in on of my fragments

I want the tabs to hide behind the keypad.

Comment: add "android-softkeyboard" tag, clarify header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can hide your tablayout when keyboard is visible

```
if(keyboardVisible)
      tabHost.setVisibility( View.GONE );    
 else
      tabHost.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
```

refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4737265/6414107) to detect keyboard visibility

Comment: Can't this be done in the fragment rather than in the config. Because this code didn't make any effect in the app

Comment: I tried your code It worked!!! but the Full page is invisible including of the Tab alone.

Comment: Thanks @SaravInfern